# Record Points on a picture

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, heatmap

i would like to work on an application that allows the user to "click" on a picture and the location of the click is recorded. The catch is that if the application is re-sized, then the point needs to stay where the user clicked. I was initially going to do it with a point that is converted to a percentage of the picture size, but not sure if there is a better approach?

```
 Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Dim em As MouseEventArgs = e
    Dim Xpos As Double = ((Convert.ToDouble(em.X) / Convert.ToDouble(PictureBox1.Width)) * 100)
    Dim ypos As Double = ((Convert.ToDouble(em.Y) / Convert.ToDouble(PictureBox1.Height)) * 100)
End Sub
```

What i'm trying to asses is the following what i'm trying to do is create a transparent circle at the point the user clicked of size "X" and then use information collected about that point to create a density map.

This information then needs to be combined with other points to create a "heat map" type of scenario.

Any suggestions or pointing in the right direction would be great.

Comment: If I understand you correctly all you need to do is store the picture size width x height and all the points the user clicked as coordinates of so many unit across and down. If the picture is resized then work out what the percentage increase or decrease is and apply the same to the user points. Depending on how you allow the picture to be resized (keep aspect ration or not) you may have to apply separate changes to the units across and down or the same calculation to both.

Comment: Thats about right. This worked in end and i was able to get around the resizing of the image by recording the points in a table and when they resize, reload all the points.